# Keda RabbitMQ - Keda not spawning additional jobs when queue has few messages

Tags: keda, keda-scaledjob

I have a Keda Scaledjob configured to spawn 1 job per message having the state 'ready' in RabbitMQ.

It has a max replica count set to 70.

Observed:

- When there are many messages in the queue, let's say 300, Keda correctly creates new jobs to reach the max replica count limit => So there are 70 running jobs each consuming 1 message from the queue.
- When there are few messages in the queue, let's say 1 Ready and 1 Unacked, Keda refuses to create a new job even if there's enough resources in the cluster.
  It's like waiting until the current running job finishes to spawn a new job.

Here's my Keda configuration :

```
---
# Reference - https://keda.sh/docs/2.0/concepts/scaling-jobs/
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledJob
metadata:
  name: scaledjob-puppeteer
  labels:
    environment: development
    app: puppeteer-display
spec:
  jobTargetRef:
    parallelism: 1                            # [max number of desired pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#controlling-parallelism)
    completions: 1                            # [desired number of successfully finished pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#controlling-parallelism)
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 7200               # (2 hours) Specifies the duration in seconds relative to the startTime that the job may be active before the system tries to terminate it; value must be positive integer
    backoffLimit: 2                           # Specifies the number of retries before marking this job failed. Defaults to 6
    template:
      spec:
        volumes:
          ...
        containers:
          ...
  pollingInterval: 10
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  maxReplicaCount: 75
  triggers:
    - type: rabbitmq
      metadata:
        protocol: amqp
        queueName: tasks
        mode: QueueLength
        value: "1"
      authenticationRef:
        name: keda-trigger-auth-rabbitmq-conn
---
```

How to make Keda to create a job whenever the queue has >= 1 message ?

Edit: It seems like it waits for at least 1 hour before creating the new job.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the missing scalingStrategy setting. You can add following configuration:

```
  scalingStrategy:
    strategy: accurate
```

The *accurate* setting is used when you consume messages from your queue instead of locking the messages. This is often used in other message queues.

For reference you can look into https://keda.sh/docs/2.7/concepts/scaling-jobs/
You can find further information about the scaling strategies in the details section.